# How to fix problem with use ion-checkboxes in Ionic v3?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I have a problem with use ion-checkbox in Ionic v3. In this (https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-2huhxr?file=pages%2Fhome%2Fhome.ts) ,

if you change the state of ion-checkbox which is responsible for displaying the checkbox for each item in the list to true, when viewTracks$ is updated, after 5 seconds, the list items become invisible.

If ion-checkbox is not set to true, when updating, all data is displayed correctly.

How can this problem be solved? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Modify the question, add something that you have tried

Comment: I tried to reproduce the issue on my end using your stackblitz, but it is not reproduced. Can you please elaborate on this.

Comment: @SunnyParekh When the data first loads, try clicking on the checkbox "Display ion-checkbox for each item in the list". And when the data is updated they (list items) will disappear from the template.

Comment: @SunnyParekh 
`setTimeout(() => {
      this.viewTracks$ = Observable.of(tracks1)
    }, 3000)`